# Installing non-pae ubuntu from USB-stick without network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, system-installation, usb, kernel

I have to install ubuntu on my old laptop(IBM thinkpad T42). When I was trying to install normal desktop version, it said that you must have non-pae kernel version.

After that I downloaded mini.iso, which has non-pae kernel, and made another usb stick for installation. But this installation needs internet connection. I have only usb wlan stick in my thinkpad and it does not recognize that wlan stick.

Is there any way to make usb stick that includes non-pae kernel version and most important packages? Or is there any different ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could customise the bootable image. There's a [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) on the Ubuntu website.

Note: For this you need a Ubuntu that's already set up (or in a virtual machine). And you need to know exactly which packages to install. Don't you have some LAN cable you can plug in? When you're using WiFi, there must be a router. And most routers do have LAN connectors.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have only mobile network router without any LAN possibilities. I have ubuntu on my another computer, but when I think more to customize my own image file, it may be little  bit too tricky. I will now go to visit my sister, who has normal LAN router. That will be easiest way to solve this, I think.